# Adapter ListView item click event

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Is this ok to do?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final ChannelPair p) {
    HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(p.ctx, p.channelList);
    p.lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    p.lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.i("CLICKED ON LV ITEM", "YEA");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Its not actually triggering the event I think. At least no item is Selected?

**UPDATE**

So I removed the stuff from the asyncTask and added it to a new Thread, so now its all in the same file. But still, I cannot get the clicks from the items

```
package com.example.tvrplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ChannelsDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public static Context ctx;
//    Activity activity;

    public ChannelsDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.ctx = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

//      Set loading spinner

//      Start looking for channels

//      When complete, show channels





        LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
        final View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);
//        Do this in a new Thread


        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final JSONArray channels;
                    String username = null;
                    String linkid = null;
                    final String apiurl = "http://192.168.2.136:8080";
                    final String channelID = null;
                    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
                    List<User> users = db.getAllUsers();  
                    for (User cn : users) {
                         linkid = cn.getLinkID();
                         username = cn.getUserName();
                     }
                     db.close();

                    final ArrayList< HashMap < String, String > > channelList = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, String > > ();
                    try {

                        if ( channelID != null ) {
                            channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username + "/" + channelID, "GET");
                            Log.i("CHANNELS", channels.toString());
                            for (int i=0; i < channels.length(); i++) { 
                                JSONObject json_data = channels.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = json_data.getString("Name");
                                String channelid = json_data.getString("ChannelID");
                                HashMap<String, String> channelObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                                  if ( json_data.getString("ParentPath") == "" ) {
                                channelObject.put("id", channelid);
                                channelObject.put("name", name);
                                channelList.add(channelObject);
//                                  }
                            }
                        } else {
                            channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET");
                            Log.i("CHANNELS", channels.toString());
                            for (int i=0; i < channels.length(); i++) { 
                                JSONObject json_data = channels.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = json_data.getString("Name");
                                String channelid = json_data.getString("ChannelID");
                                HashMap<String, String> channelObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                Log.i("CHANNEL LEN", ""+ json_data.getString("ParentID").length());
                                if ( json_data.getString("ParentID").length() < 32 ) {
                                    channelObject.put("id", channelid);
                                    channelObject.put("name", name);
                                    channelList.add(channelObject);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ((Activity)ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(ctx, channelList);
                                    ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
                                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("CLICKED ON LV ITEM", "YEA");
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                               
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start(); 
        return vw;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        persistBoolean(positiveResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);
//
        Log.v("which", Integer.toString(which));
//
        if(which == -1) { //Clear all
//          new ChannelHandler().execute(apiurl, username, linkid, vw, ctx, channelID);
        }
    }


}
```

This part is where the clicks are bound:

```
((Activity)ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(ctx, channelList);
                                    ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
                                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("CLICKED ON LV ITEM", "YEA");
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This causes a change on `UIthread` which should not be called from the background thread. Remeber never to update or `notifychange()` a `listView` from the backgound thread

Comment: Im not sure how I would do this otherwise. I have to wait for a list from a url on the web to load before I can add the items (from the web) to the adapter.

Comment: write the same code outside the AsyncTask. Write it in OnCreate() method.

Comment: So I take out the AsynTask? Let me try

Comment: just not this part. Let be in the AsyncTask HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(p.ctx, p.channelList);
    p.lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: why cant you just write your this part lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("CLICKED ON LV ITEM", "YEA");
                                        }
                                    }); outside the thread. just write it below where you initialize LV

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25339/discussion-between-harry-and-fahad-ishaque)